# Making Edge Lines Stand Out in Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, edges

I want to outline all of the tiles so they are easier to see. I need the edge lines to be clearly visible.

[image]

Comment: Is this a stylistic question (ie what should it look like), or a technical one (how do I give it a texture)?

Comment: I clarified the question.